# Installing Office SharePoint 2007 on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 Standart. I want to install Sharepoint Office Server 2007 on my server. When I try to run setup, Program Compatibility Assistant warning this message :

http://i26.tinypic.com/b495vl.png

I installed WSS 3.0 With SP2 and I try install again but problem is not solved.

How can I install Sharepoint Office Server 2007 on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: You want:
http://superuser.com/
or possibly http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/65949/installing-sharepoint-2007-on-windows-server-2008-r2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that SP2 is bundled in the MOSS installation contents. [This blog](http://keirgordon.com/post/Installing-SharePoint-on-Windows-Server-2008-R2.aspx) has a posting on how to do it, and [this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointgeneral/thread/c7091bda-867e-49a1-9bc8-c2ef847c92e7) is good reading.