# Installing Sharepoint 2007 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

we are using in our lab a clean installation of Windows Server 2008 R2 which is running as Hyper-V instance. Today we wanted to install a clean installation of Sharepoint 2007 with SP1 on this machine and we explorer an error that we are not able to install it. The setup is comes up with an error which is described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/962935 but this is not our szenario. A printscreen of this message can be found here: http://www.ronischuetz.com/images/SP_2007SP1_Inst_Error.png

@Microsoft,

my personal point of view is that it cannot be that we need to install first 2008, then Sharepoint 2007 with SP1, then SP2 and upgrade to 2008 R2. Nobody is going be happy with this solution and I hope we find a fast way how customers can install Sharepoint direclty on 2008 R2.

Anyway, thanks in advance for any further information how we should go on with this issue.

The issue is listed here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/91a6be50-9009-43c8-a37c-66cfb83d738f

Answer (score 5):

You can install SharePoint on Windows Server 2008 R2. You **don't** need to install it on Windows Server 2008 and then upgrade to Windows Server 2008 R2.

The issue is that Windows Server 2008 R2 is only compatible with Office SharePoint Server 2007 SP2.

Unfortunately, Microsoft have not released a version of SharePoint with SP2 built in, however it is fairly easy to do this yourself. You can create your own slip-streamed installation of SharePoint with SP 2 included and then install this directly onto Windows Server 2008 R2 (no upgrade required).

To slip-stream SharePoint see:

- [Create an installation source that includes software updates (Office SharePoint Server 2007)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261890.aspx)

I've done this with Office SharePoint Server 2007 SP2 and it installs fine on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I tried to do this with Sharepoint 2007 RTM (with SP2 slipstreamed) and Windows Server 2008, but the Program Compability Assistant still complained about setup.exe. However, renaming setup.exe allowed the installation to continue.

Comment: @Hirvox - you shouldn't have to rename setup.exe. Are you sure that SP2 was slipstreamed correctly?